# PCI Compliance for Paypal DoReferenceTransaction

Tags: paypal

I am creating a payment system which will keep on charging buyers using Paypal's DoReferenceTransaction API. I am just storing the last transaction reference (no credit card details) in my database. Do I need to be PCI compliant for this? If yes, then how can I proceed?

Comment: PCI compliance is applicable if you are storing raw CC info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are liable to PCI compliance. See the [PCI FAQ](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/) for details:

> Q: To whom does PCI apply? A: PCI applies to ALL organizations or
>   merchants, regardless of size or number of transactions, that **accepts**,
>   **transmits** or **stores** any cardholder data. Said another way, if any
>   customer of that organization ever pays the merchant directly using a
>   credit card or debit card, then the PCI DSS requirements apply.
>
> Q: What is defined as ‘cardholder data’? A: Cardholder data is any
>   personally identifiable data associated with a cardholder. This could
>   be an account number, expiration date, name, address, social security
>   number, etc. All personally identifiable information associated with
>   the cardholder that is stored, processed, or transmitted is also
>   considered cardholder data.

Your site **accepts** credit card data that is **transmitted** to PayPal. You can read about how to be PCI compliant here: https://www.paypal.com/pcicompliance

Answer (score 0):

Because Reference Transactions effectively tokenize the credit card data for storage and later use it is considered a PCI compliant solution.